# What are reset periods/dates in relation with interest rate swaps?

Tags: interest-rates, interest-rate-swap

Let's assume I have a 2-year fixed-floating swap, the floating leg has a quarterly reset.

Does this mean the valuation is done every 3 months for the floating leg? (and the total value of these 4 quarters paid once at the end of year 1)

Does this mean the valuation and payments are due every 3 months for the floating leg?

Does this mean the valuation happens once at the start of the year 1, and payments are due every 3 months for the floating leg?

Or does this mean something else?

Comment: You have recently asked 5 questions about basic swap terminology. Perhaps you should read a basic introduction to swaps first as your questions are becoming increasingly difficult to follow. (For example in this question I am not sure what you mean by Valuation, or how it relates to your previous questions).

Comment: Apologies for the confusing wording, I'm new to this stuff and just trying to prep for the first year of my Actuary course. In future I will make sure I am clearer.

Comment: Suppose I borrow money from a bank at a floating interest rate (this is just a loan, not a swap). 'Quarterly reset' of the interest rate means at the beginning of each quarter the bank tells me what the interest rate will be for the coming quarter (a process called 'fixing' the rate) and at the end of the 3 months (1 quarter of a year) I pay three months of interest at that rate to the bank. There is no 'valuation' or 'totaling of value'. It is a simple enough process, whether for a loan or a plain vanilla swap.